# Does it make sense to show *both* the standard deviation *and* the standard error in a single plot?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error

[image]

Inasmuch as people plot

- **SD**-based measures of spread (e.g. error bars) on top of means to visualise the variance in an observed *sample*, OR
- **SEM**-based measures of spread to estimate the *population* value of that mean,

I am wondering if the visualisation of *both at the same time*, as in the box&whisker plot below*, has any synergetic interpretation or value.

*: Figure 1D from [this paper](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/357/6351/596.full), caption reads: "Error bars represent ±1 SD, and boxes represent ± 1 SEM."

Comment: If the dots represent the data, then the caption cannot possibly be correct: the standard errors of the mean are substantially smaller than shown by the boxes (and there aren't any "error bars" in evidence).  It is rare for a boxplot to be based on SDs in the first place: they are intended to be robust and therefore are usually based on the IQR or something comparable.  That clearly is not the case in these pictures either!  Please clarify what this plot is showing, because that's essential for understanding your question.

Comment: The dots do represent the data. I am not sure what you mean when you say there are no error bars in evidence. Perhaps I was wrong to refer to the whiskers of the box as error bars?

Comment: Also, could you please explain why displaying distribution spread as IQRs instead of SDs is more "robust"? I'd like to understand this better. I've edited my question to clarify where the figure comes from. The y axis represents a detection threshold, that's being compared between 4 groups (although I guess this doesn't really directly concern my question). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Robustness, in the sense of working well for a wide variety of distributions, is a property that comes in part from resistance, in the sense of not changing much when some part of the data are arbitrarily changed.  Although the IQR may change when up to 25% of the data are altered, it will not move beyond the range of the original data.  Statistics (and graphics based on them) derived from SDs can change by arbitrarily large amounts if only a single data value is changed.  Such statistics are the opposite of robust, which disqualifies them for general-purpose exploratory use.

Comment: BTW, the whiskers are in no wise ever considered "error bars": the only similarity is graphical.  You might find it useful to review some of our more relevant posts on [boxplots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=boxplot).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! So going back to the plot, do you think the authors mistakenly report that the boxes represent the standard error? And does it make any sense at all to display box&whiskers as SE&SD respectively; or would it have been more helpful to visualise these data as SE&IQR (or *just* IQR)?

Comment: Boxplots don't display SEs of anything.  They were designed as a robust graphical representation of properties related to *location* and *spread* in a way that will reveal potential univariate *outliers.*  The graphic in this question *might* display standard boxplots, but only under the assumption that there are many instances where data points overlap. Regardless, the visible points give us information about the *minimum* data set sizes and about the *maximum* possible spreads, and from this we can deduce the boxplots do not represent SEs of the mean (or median).